# Advantages of using ostream& vs cout

Tags: c++

I've heard that `ostream&` is better to use than `cout` when outputting something (strings, etc). Why is that? I could be wrong, but aren't `ostream`s easier to manipulate and work with than simple `cout` statements?

Comment: `cout` is an `ostream`. I don't understand the premise of your question.

Comment: I think you are confused.  The wisdom is, in a printing function, instead of just using `std::cout`, have that function take an `ostream&`, and then print to that.  That way the caller of the function can decide where the output goes by passing in `std::cout` or some other stream object

Comment: Basically is there an advantage to returning an ostream& in a print function vs returning a regular cout statement?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would return _"a regular cout statement"_?

Comment: To make it clear and repeat it: [`std::cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is an object of type `std::ostream`. It's declared as `extern std::ostream cout;`.

Comment: @NathanOliver So if I understand correctly, you basically have more control over the output?

Comment: @ethanh Yes.  You don't always want to print to `std::cout`.  You might want it to print to a file, or to `std::cerr` or a `std::stringstream`.  Taking an `ostream&` gives you that flexibilty.

Comment: @NathanOliver How does _"returning an ostream& in a print function"_ improve the flexibility?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Just a print function that returns a cout instead of taking in an ostream& and returning that? Is there an advantage to doing so?

Comment: Please show some actual code because your description doesn't make much sense. I've never seen a function that returns `std::cout`. Somehow you are confusing "return" and "print". And I think you are confusing "return" and "take as argument".

Comment: @NathanOliver Ohh okay, cool! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ThomasSablik Hence, I start with my comment with *I think you are confused.*

Comment: I don't have any code, just a question I had. Sorry, I should've worded it better. When I say print I'm just talking about a function that simply returns something (i.e. "printing" a string). Either a cout statement or an ostream&.

Comment: @NathanOliver But I think answering this question or giving recommendations without clarification makes it even worse.

Comment: There is a big difference between printing something and returning something. You would never return a `std::cout` object. A function can take a reference to a `std::ostream` object and use this object to "print" or it can directly print through `std::cout`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: streams are returned by reference quite often.  The fact that `operator<<()` and `operator>>()` return the stream is what allows you to write `cout << a << b << c;` or `if (cin >> x)`    But you are absolutely correct that there is a big difference between data "printed" (sent to a stream) and a function's return value.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, streams are returned often. But returning a stream doesn't give you flexibility. It allows chaining. Passing a stream to a function gives you flexibility (because now you can choose where the function actually "prints"). And I've never seen a function returning `std::cout`.

Answer (score 3):

Let us look at an example of passing an `ostream` reference to a function:

```
void My_Function(std::ostream& error_stream)
{
     error_stream << "Error in My_Function";
}
```

By using `std::ostream&`, I can pass other streams to the function: a file stream, a string stream, `std::cout`, to name a few.  I can also create (derive) a custom `Logging` class from `std::ostream` and pass a logging stream to the function.

If the function only outputs to `std::cout`, I have lost the ability to use a logging stream, or have the text written to a file (for a record).  Instead, the text will **always** go to `std::cout`.  This is quite a headache when you want to record issues with a GUI-based application (as GUI applications don't have a console window for output). Outputting to a file records the output vs console output that just scrolls away.

Think about generic programming, and the ability to "plug and play" with other modules.  Using `std::ostream&` allows functions to output to anything derived from `std::ostream`, including output streams that haven't been designed yet!

**Example Usage**

Here are some example usages:

```
struct usb_ostream : public std::ostream
{
  // Writes to the USB port
  //...
};

int main()
{
  usb_ostream USB_Output;
  My_Function(USB_Output); // Writes text to USB port

  My_Function(std::cerr);  // Writes to the standard error stream.

  std::ofstream my_file("errors.txt");
  My_Function(my_file);    // Saves error text to a file.

  // Of course:
  My_Function(std::cout);  // Write the text to the console.

  // Maybe we want to parse the output.  
  std::ostringstream error_stream;
  My_Function(error_stream);
  const std::string error_text = error_stream.str();
  // Parse the string ...

  return 0;
}
```

Notice that in the `main()` function, there is only one version of `My_Function()` called.  There are no changes necessary to `My_Function()` to make `My_Function()` output to various devices, strings, or output channels.

Comment: It is possible to redirect cout, change its rdbuf, although of course it is better if you don't need to.